# Are there fuzzy logic type extensions for Drools 7.x?

Tags: jboss, logic, drools, rules, fuzzy

Drools-chances was an initial implementation for fuzzy logic.  Discussion in 2013 on http://blog.athico.com/2009/05/take-your-chance.html indicated that there might be progress for the brave.  Since I plan on implementing a fuzzy rule system it would be good to know if there are alternatives to FuzzyJess.